# If Statement Has Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, if-statement, raspberry-pi, minecraft

My raspberry pi python code contains.

```
try:
   while True:
              blockHits = mc.events.pollBlockHits()
if blockHits:
            for blockHit in blockHits
```

Whenever I start the code it says invalid syntax and highlights the if.
It's for minecraft by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either failed to show us your `except` or `finally` block that belongs with your [`try` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), but the `if` statement must still be part of the `try` suite. However, it is not indented enough to be part of the `try` suite.

Indent your `if` statement to be in the `try:` block, or put it after the `finally:` or `except:` suite. If you don't have either, you'll need to add one, you cannot use `try:` without one.

You appear to be trying to type out the code in [this post](http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2013/05/raspberry-pi-minecraft-block-events.html); you'll notice that the `if` is inside the `while` loop there:

```
try:
    while True:
        #Get the block hit events
        blockHits = mc.events.pollBlockHits()
        # if a block has been hit
        if blockHits:
            # for each block that has been hit
            for blockHit in blockHits:
                #Create and run the exploding block class in its own thread
                # pass the position of the block, fuse time in seconds and blast radius
                # threads are used so multiple exploding blocks can be created
                explodingBlock = ExplodingBlock(blockHit.pos, 3, 3)
                explodingBlock.daemon
                explodingBlock.start()
        time.sleep(0.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("stopped")
```

Indentation is very important in Python; it serves the role of grouping statements into blocks (suites) that belong together, and your attempt broke the expectations of how the `try` suite was supposed to end.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a beginner. Can you show me an example please?

Comment: @CreaghDuggan: I have no idea what you are trying to do with the code. What part might throw an exception, and what should happen if an exception is thrown? What should happen if no exception occurs?

Comment: @CreaghDuggan: the indentation is all wrong in that post. They link to the actual original source: http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2013/05/raspberry-pi-minecraft-block-events.html